# BBB [debian] How to execute LSBInitscript AFTER loading device tree overlay?

Tags: linux, debian, startup, beagleboneblack, device-tree

My program runs on BBB (debian) and depends on device tree overlay (SPI).

1. Overlay compiled and added to */etc/default/capemgr*: **CAPE=BB-DSPI1**.
2. LSB-script that executes my prog added to the system with update-rc.d, **Required-Start** parameter is **$all**
3. Running script maually after booting with **start** parameter works as expected.
4. During boot-up sequence execution fails, since **/sys/devices/ocp.3/481a0000.spi/spi_master/** not found.
5. I used to have another BBB configured same way. There was no issue.

Can anyone explain how to run my prog at startup?

Answer (score 0):

edit script:

**# Required-Start:    capemgr.sh**